# iTunes wont sync items to iPhone after Family Sharing set up

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, home-sharing, family-sharing

I ran into issue where my iTunes on Windows wont sync any data to iPhone 6 after I set up Family Sharing. Any ideas how to fix this?

There are no error messages, photos sync just ok but music does not appear on the iPhone after syncing or clicking Autofill button. iTunes version is 12.2.1. iPhone is on iOS 8.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured what was the problem. First of all its not family sharing but new Apple music which is in the cloud now and prevents from downloading songs from iTunes to your iPhone. So if you go to Settings --> Music and disable Show Apple music it restores the ability to transfer songs in old fashion from iTunes. See attached screenshot.

[image: Disabled Apple music]